# Start up circuit

Tags: voltage, current, cmos

I am currently testing the beta-multiplier operation, when I add the start-up circuit to ensure the "zero current" state does not occurs. I understand the problem theoretically, however, I do not know how to test if this works in simulation. I think that I can try to run one circuit with the start up circuit and one with not, and i have to force zero current to both. But how do I do that?

**So my questions are:**
How does one force a voltage to a node, or current to a wire to test?
How can one simulate the start up circuit to make sure it works?

Answer (score 1):

Startup is transient behavior, therefore a transient simulation is required.

One method would be to perform a transient simulation and use a piecewise linear voltage source to supply the circuit. A voltage ramp should be specified that is zero first and then ramps up to the final voltage.

This simulation should be done for all corners and also using a Monte Carlo simulation on top of it.

More fancy voltage ramps  (first up, then a fraction of the supply voltage down, up again, ...) could be used to check the robustness of the startup circuit. Sometimes capacitors retain a charge and the second rising ramp would show a different behavior in such a case.